# Verify if user is approved by admin before login

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems

Hello I followed the tutorial [How To: Require admin to activate account before sign_in](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Require-admin-to-activate-account-before-sign_in)
 to verify that the user is approved by the admin before he can connect.

I would like to add the condition to test that it is approved to connect

here is my controller **session_controller.rb**

```
class SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController
before_action :set_email

 def new
  super
 end

def create
 self.resource = warden.authenticate!(auth_options)
 set_flash_message(:notice, :signed_in) if is_navigational_format?
 sign_in(resource_name, resource)

 if !session[:return_to].blank?
  redirect_to session[:return_to]
  session[:return_to] = nil

 else
  respond_with resource, :location => after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
end

end

def confirm_email
 user = User.find_by_confirm_token(params[:id])
 if user
  user.email_activate
  flash[:success] = "Welcome to the Sample App! Your email has been 
confirmed.
  Please sign in to continue."
  redirect_to signin_url
 else
  flash[:error] = "Sorry. User does not exist"
  redirect_to root_url
end
end


def set_email
 @email = params[:email];
 @user1 = params[:user];
end



end
```

Thanks

Comment: "I would like to add the condition to test that it is approved to connect" to what and as what? Are you trying to sing_in as an admin or regular user?

Comment: it's for regular user!


Before the simple user connection, I test if it has been approved by the administrator.


(After registering a new member, the administrator approves the registration or not.)

Comment: I am assuming you have used devise for sign_up/registration too? If yes, devise takes care of it itself if you have configured everything correctly. If you have done that then what problem/error are you facing?

Comment: the problem is that even if the user is not approved, the user connects.
I only want those who are approved to have the opportunity to connect

Comment: You posted the code where you sign_up after verifying_email; and then you can sign_in. Does email verification work?
Post the code where sign_in happens. That is what the tutorial is for: Admin activating an account before user sign-in.

Comment: the "create" method also manages the connection with the call of the sign_in method.

I put down a solution that I think is good

Answer (score 0):

```
def create
 self.resource = warden.authenticate!(auth_options)
 if current_user.approved?
   set_flash_message(:notice, :signed_in) if is_navigational_format?
   sign_in(resource_name, resource)
   if !session[:return_to].blank?
     redirect_to session[:return_to]
     session[:return_to] = nil
   else
     respond_with resource, :location => after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
   end
 else
   sign_out current_user

   redirect_to "/"    
 end
end
```